# WPF Desktop Application layout dilemma

Tags: c#, wpf, gridpanel, gridsplitter, dockpanel

I want to develope my first real WPF Desktop Application. It's quite a lot of time since my last desktop application, which was developed with .NET 2.0 and Windows Forms. Since i have to develope a new Desktop Application, and i can take the advantage of .NET 4.0 i would really like to use WPF.

I am reading some online tutorial and documentation to choose the right way to do it, but i am a little lost with the new controls.

Basically i need a panel which show some textboxes and label above a datagrid.
Do you think that i can achieve such a result with gridpanel control ?
Thank you.

[image: Sample]

Comment: If you mean the Grid control, yes that definitely the appropriate panel to use. Here you would use a number of nested Grids. In your view shown above you could use a Grid with 6 rows, which in its 3rd row contains another Grid with 4 rows and 4 columns for all the Labels, TextBoxes and ComboBoxes. The 5th row of the outer Grid would contain a DataGrid for the table data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WPF you usually use several different controls. **Control composition** in WPF is a major feature and you'll gain a lot by knowing it and taking advantage of it.

When looking at your screen i divide it in two major parts:
  - campi di ricerca 
  - resultati

For these two i'd use a Grid with two rows and one column.
The ricerca area could use a DockPanel with the header aligned at the top and aother Grid With Fill contents.

... and so on, so on.

My best advice is for you to learn about **WPF Composition**

Hope i've helped a little bit

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use a [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.aspx), with multiple rows and columns.

See the example on MSDN

```
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ShowGridLines="True" Width="250" Height="100">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0">2005 Products Shipped</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">Quarter 1</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">Quarter 2</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">Quarter 3</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0">50000</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">100000</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">150000</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="3">Total Units: 300000</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: But consider nesting Grids. That will make your layout much easier.